# Get contrast for each channel in an image opencv python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, color-space, contrast

How to calculate each channel contrast in images?
Since they are lot of contrast definitions out [there](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contrast_(vision)#Formula)

1. Webar Contrast
2. Michelson Contrast
3. RMS contrast

I need to calculate these contrasts.

Comment: The author does not define C as contrast. I suspect they are just the red, green and blue channel values.

Comment: yes, I misunderstood

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
from numpy import mean, sqrt, square
im = Image.open("leaf.jpg") # Image file name
pixels = list(im.getdata())
width, height = im.size
pixels = np.asarray([pixels[i * width:(i + 1) * width] for i in range(height)], dtype=int)

ch_1 = pixels[:,:,0]
ch_2 = pixels[:,:,1]
ch_3 = pixels[:,:,2]

rms_of_ch1 = sqrt(mean(square(ch_1)))
rms_of_ch2 = sqrt(mean(square(ch_2)))
rms_of_ch3 = sqrt(mean(square(ch_3)))
```

Comment: Thanks @Shmn, u used the RMS contrast to calculate the contrast isn't it?

Comment: You are welcome @coder_v_3.0. Yes, I used RMS contrast.

Comment: I've upvoted but I need weber contrast way to calculate the contrast